# POST data from form to form

Tags: django, forms

I want to use POST data to partially pre-fill the next form.

I have a form on one page...

```
<form method="POST" action='{% url 'screen_many' %}'>
```

Passing stuff to a view that displays a second form.

```
def screen_many(request):
    #...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SurveyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            saved = form.save(commit=False)
            saved.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = SurveyForm(initial={'student': request.POST['selected_student']})
```

Of course, the `if` branch is taken and the second form complains about validation errors.

EDIT: As requested, my forms code...

```
class SurveyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    nsf_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Never',), 
        (2, '',),
        (3, 'Sometimes',),
        (4, '',),
        (5, 'Frequently',),
    ) 

    nmv_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'Not Descriptive'),
        (2, ''),
        (3, 'Moderately Descriptive'),
        (4, ''),
        (5, 'Very Descriptive'),
    )

    aggbs_0 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('aggbs_0')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    aggbs_1 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('aggbs_1')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    aggbs_2 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('aggbs_2')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    aggbs_3 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('aggbs_3')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    aggbs_4 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('aggbs_4')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    aggbs_5 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('aggbs_5')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    aggbs_6 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('aggbs_6')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    aggbs_7 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('aggbs_7')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)

    si_0 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nmv_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('si_0')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    si_1 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nmv_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('si_1')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    si_2 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nmv_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('si_2')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    si_3 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nmv_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('si_3')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    si_4 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nmv_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('si_4')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    si_5 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nmv_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('si_5')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    si_6 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nmv_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('si_6')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    si_7 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nmv_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('si_7')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)

    cfiab_0 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfiab_0')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfiab_1 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfiab_1')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfiab_2 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfiab_2')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfiab_3 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfiab_3')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfiab_4 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfiab_4')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfiab_5 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfiab_5')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfiab_6 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfiab_6')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfiab_7 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfiab_7')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)

    cfimb_0 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfimb_0')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfimb_1 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfimb_1')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfimb_2 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfimb_2')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfimb_3 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfimb_3')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfimb_4 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfimb_4')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfimb_5 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfimb_5')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfimb_6 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfimb_6')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfimb_7 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfimb_7')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)
    cfimb_8 = forms.TypedChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizRadioRenderer), choices=nsf_CHOICES, label=Survey._meta.get_field_by_name('cfimb_8')[0].verbose_name, empty_value=0)

    class Meta:
        model = Survey

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
                'surveyset',
                'student',
                Fieldset('Critical Events Index',
                        HTML("""
                        <p>Check each behavior from the list below that the child has exhibited during this school year. Complete this using your knowledge of during this school year.</p>
                        """),
                        'cei_0','cei_1','cei_2','cei_3','cei_4','cei_5','cei_6','cei_7','cei_8','cei_9','cei_10','cei_11','cei_12','cei_13','cei_14','cei_15',),

                Fieldset('Aggressive Behavior Scale',
                        HTML("""
                        <p>The numbers one through five are used to show the estimate of the frequency with which each item occurs. Choose the number that best represents the amount of times this behavior happens. Complete this scale using your knowledge of during this school year.</p>
                        """),'aggbs_0','aggbs_1','aggbs_2','aggbs_3','aggbs_4','aggbs_5','aggbs_6','aggbs_7',),

                Fieldset('Social Interaction',
                        HTML("""
                        <p>The numbers one through seven are used to show the estimate of the frequency with which each item occurs. Choose the number that best represents the amount of times this behavior happens. Complete this scale using your knowledge of during this school year.</p>
                        """),'si_0','si_1','si_2','si_3','si_4','si_5','si_6','si_7',),

                Fieldset('Combined Frequency Index Adaptive Behavior',
                    HTML("""
                        <p>The numbers one through five are used to show the estimate of the frequency with which each item occurs. Choose the number that best represents the amount of times this behavior happens. Complete this scale using your knowledge of during this school year.</p>
                        """), 'cfiab_0','cfiab_1','cfiab_2','cfiab_3','cfiab_4','cfiab_5','cfiab_6','cfiab_7',),

                Fieldset('Combined Frequency Index Maladaptive Behavior',
                    HTML("""<p>The numbers one through five are used to show the estimate of the frequency with which each item occurs. Choose the number that best represents the amount of times this behavior happens. Complete this scale using your knowledge of during this school year.</p>"""),
                'cfimb_0','cfimb_1','cfimb_2','cfimb_3','cfimb_4','cfimb_5','cfimb_6','cfimb_7','cfimb_8',),

                )
        super(SurveyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And my model...

Comment: Maybe I need to overload `__init__` in my SurveyForm?

Comment: Please post your form code.

Comment: @Brandon take a look :)

Comment: What kind of validation errors are you getting?

Comment: Surveyset* This field is required. Student* This field is required.

Comment: It doesn't prefill the form. it doesn't hit the `else:
        form = SurveyForm(initial={'student': request.POST['selected_student']})` branch because I am submitting stuff from post. Instead it goes straight for `if request.method == 'POST'`